# When Mabel and Dipper travel back in time, where do their old selves go?

Tags: time-travel, gravity-falls

When Mabel and Dipper first time travel in the episode "The Time Traveller's Pig" (S1E09), it seems like they reverse back in time. They appear at the Mystery Shack and they run out. But when Dipper meets Wendy, she is just at the point right before they do the ball throw. She then asks Dipper where he was — implying that he just disappeared or something like that. Later in the episode when they go back to the first episode setting, you can see their past selves fighting the gnomes.

**So what happened to the original Mabel and Dipper?**

Answer (score 2):

This does sound like a goof/plot hole, like the others in [this list](http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_goofs). You're right; they arrive back in time at a point where they would see themselves.

If it was intentional by the show runners, it might have been to just show the concept of the inherent paradox-avoiding "time curse" during the first do-over without muddling it with multiple Pine twins.